# How to debug crash which happened on Windows Mobile

Tags: debugging, windows-mobile, crash-dumps

I have created a mobile app for Windows Mobile. Sometime it crashes and I have crash dump file  (.kdmp) from mobile. But how to analyse it? I have WinDbg. I provided .exe which is created while deployment.For symbol path it requires .pdb file but for ARM Release it is not creating .pdb file. It creates .pdb file for x86 Release only.

How can I proceed further? I used below link but I couldn't proceed.
http://www.windowsfordevices.com/c/a/Windows-For-Devices-Articles/Findin...

If there is any way that it creates iwtrace.txt on device then also it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can open crash dumps using Visual studio, see this msdn [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk551230%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), WinDbg currently only supports x86 and x64 at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently trying to debug crash dumps for ARM in release too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916756/analysing-kdmp-files-in-ce-watson-dump-viewer

You say you don't have pdb generated for ARM Release - have you checked your project settings?:

Go to project settings (for EVC3 select the FileView tab, right click your project and hit settings). Make sure the settings for is your ARM Release config, then go to the Link tab and make sure "Generate debug info" is selected. Build your solution and you should then see a pdb file in your output directory.